# ¿Cómo conocer la ruta más larga en GoogleMaps API (Direction matrix)?

Tags: javascript, api, parametros

Buen día grupo, tengo una inquietud que no he podido resolver, he navegado por todo internet sin poder encontrar una posible solución, resulta que necesito conocer la DISTANCIA MAS LARGA entre 2 direcciones utilizando la API de GOOGLE MAPS (Direction o Distance Matrix), de las ALTERNATIVAS que MAPS da, traer la distancia más LARGA, en el caso que exista mas de una RUTA.

He utilizado los parametros de traffic_model = pessimistic, departure_time, mode y con ninguno he logrado obtener la RUTA más LARGA entre mis dos puntos. La URL queda

La DISTANCIA que deseo conocer es de la RUTA señalada con las flechas y no la ruta mas OPTIMA que es la que GOOGLE MAPS siempre me da.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay algun parametro que de deberia considerar para poder obtener la RUTA menos OPTIMA, la más larga??

```js
function getDistance(url) {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var distance = data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
  
  return distance; 
}
```

De aquí construyo la URL

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distance_matrix/json?origin=CHIUBURNA,+MERIDA,+97203&destination=DOLORES+OTERO,+Mérida,+Yucatán,+97270&mode=driving&departure_time=now&traffic_model=pessimistic&key="MI API"`

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has leído la documentación de la API que estás usando?

Comment: Así es, de hecho como comento, con los parámetros que he incluido no consigo lo que necesito, algo seguramente no me esta funcionando. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Justamente por eso mismo, `The Distance Matrix API provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations, and consists of rows containing duration and distance values for each pair.`, en otras palabras, te da la ruta más óptima.

Comment: Es correcto, el objetivo principal de las API es proporcionar las rutas mas OPTIMAS sin embargo, existe la posibilidad de que haya mas de 1 una ruta optima, sin embargo las API solo me devuelven justamente la MAS CORTA, lo que yo busco es lo contrario, de las ALTERNATIVAS que haya busco la MENOS OPTIMA, LA MAS LARGA, me explico?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Sí, si te explicas y sin griteríos de preferencia (escribir en mayúsculas equivale a ello). A lo que iba es que **Distance Matrix API te da la ruta más óptima** esa es su función. Mira la documentación de `Directions`:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview y aquí tienes una pregunta relacionada en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50113321/3613462 y una lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Grcs por tu comentario amigo, sin embargo el escribir en mayúsculas no es con la intención de gritarte como TU o algunos lo interpretan, es hacer énfasis en las palabras que deseo resaltar. Y sobre tu lectura altamente recomendable igualmente gracias, pero nadie nace sabiendolo todo y si estoy aqui es para buscar apoyo y no críticas.

Comment: Exacto, nadie nace sabiendo, por eso mismo, las recomendaciones para tener una buena estructura de una pregunta porque una pregunta bien enfocada, es una pregunta medio resuelta. Con respecto a lo último, apoyo siempre encuentras, que te incomode la lectura sugerida es tema aparte, mis redes sociales están disponibles si deseas conversar.

Comment: Amigo creo que con esa actitud mejor deberías abstenerte de "APOYAR", excelente día.

Comment: Lo dudo, esta misma actitud me ha generado un gran número de amigos por estos lares y ha llevado sonrisas a muchos usuarios que tenían problemas en su momento :D El tiempo y la experiencia son valiosos, algunos usuarios lo saben valorar, otros no, y como te dije antes, mis redes sociales están disponibles para quien deseen aprender, les comparto con mucho gusto y cariño.  Que también tengas un excelente día. Saludos :D

Comment: voto por cerrar esta pregunta el OP no colabora.

Comment: sigo sin entender que obtiene y que espera obtener, osea como sabe que el dato que le dan es incorrecto y presume que le falta algo a su codigo, es ambiguo faltan datos o invetigacion?